# What's the right Scala and Java collection combination to use with nested JAXB?

Tags: scala, jaxb

Working with JAXB, the standard way of dealing with a list of "nested" resource representations (e.g. `<products><product>X</product><product>Y</product></products>` is to create a wrapper object, which in Java might look like this (borrowed from [Jhopify](https://github.com/csaunders/jhopify)):

```
@XmlType(name = "")
@XmlRootElement(name = "products")
public class ProductList {
  List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();

  @XmlElement(name = "product", required = true)
  public List<Product> getProducts() { return products; }

  public void setProducts(List<Product> products) { this.products = products; }
}
```

However I'm struggling to determine exactly which collection objects to use when translating this to Scala. There's a good introductory post to doing this on the [Mostly Blather blog](http://www.mostlyblather.com/2010/02/scala-with-resteasy-jax-rs.html), which uses a Scala Iterable implicitly converted (using JavaConversions) to and from a JCollection.

This works great for marshalling a JAXB class to XML but unfortunately when unmarshalling this throws `UnsupportedOperationException` on each `add` attempt. Based on the last paragraph on this [Scala documentation page](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_46.html) it looks like this happens because Java does not distinguish between mutable and immutable collections in their type.

To deal with the unmarshalling, I've tried an alternative approach specifically using mutable objects:

```
@XmlType(name = "")
@XmlRootElement(name = "products")
class ProductList {
  private var products: Buffer[Product] = new ArrayBuffer[Product]

  @XmlElement(name = "product", required = true)
  def getProducts: JList[Product]  = products

  def setProducts(products: JList[Product]) {
    this.products = products
  }
}
```

But unfortunately with this approach, unmarshalling gives me an exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: ProductList.getProducts()Ljava/util/Collection;
```

**Edit:** as per Travis' request, here is my unmarshalling code:

```
val jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ProductList.getClass())
val unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller()
val root = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new StringReader(responseString)), ProductList.getClass())
val r = root.getValue().asInstanceOf[ProductList]
val representations = r.getProducts.asScala.toList // Uses scalaj
```

So I'm a bit stumped... I've looked at [scalaj's available conversions](https://github.com/scalaj/scalaj-collection/blob/master/README.markdown) too but nothing obvious jumps out. Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you post your unmarshalling code? I've done something similar with JAXB from Scala, and what you have looks like it *should* work. Here's a complete working example:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation._

class Thing {
  @scala.reflect.BeanProperty var name: String = _
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "things")
class Things {
  import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
  import scala.collection.mutable.Buffer

  private var things: Buffer[Thing] = Buffer[Thing]()

  @XmlElement(name = "thing", required = true)
  def getThings: java.util.List[Thing] = this.things

  def setThings(things: java.util.List[Thing]) {
    this.things = things
  }
}
```

I'll write the test code in Scala as well, but it would work identically in Java.

```
object Things {
  import java.io.StringReader
  import java.io.StringWriter
  import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val thing1 = new Thing
    val thing2 = new Thing
    thing1.setName("Thing 1")
    thing2.setName("Thing 2")

    val list: java.util.List[Thing] = new java.util.ArrayList[Thing]
    list.add(thing1)
    list.add(thing2)

    val things = new Things
    things.setThings(list)

    val context = JAXBContext.newInstance(classOf[Things])
    val writer = new StringWriter
    context.createMarshaller.marshal(things, writer)

    println(writer.toString)

    val readThings = context.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(
      new StringReader(writer.toString)
    ).asInstanceOf[Things]

    println("Size: " + readThings.getThings.size)
    println("Name of first: " + readThings.getThings.get(0).getName)
  }
}
```

This compiles and produces the output you'd expect.

Comment: Many thanks for sharing this Travis. I've posted my unmarshalling code as requested. I'm steadily changing my code to be basically the same as yours but so far still getting the `NoSuchMethodError` - I will keep you posted...

Comment: Update: my code now looks much more like Travis's and is working! The problem was in my unmarshalling code - I'm trying to track it down more precisely now

Comment: Right, the problem related to my `ProductList.getClass()` calls - there was never a ProductList object (just a class), so I'm not sure how these ever even compiled (they're not compiling now). So anyway thanks again Travis - your code is the definitive answer